# How to add shardCollection action role to an user in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to allow a user who has **readWriteAnyDatabase** access to mongo to be able to shardCollection.

```
{
    "role" : "readWriteShard",
    "roles" : [
        "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "clusterManager" // tried with and without this role

    ],
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "cluster" : true
            },
            "actions" : [
                "enableSharding"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After I created the user like this:

```
{
"user" : "usershard",
"roles" : [
    //this is useless here, at it's inherited by readWriteShard
    {
        "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "db" : "admin"
    },
    {
        "role" : "readWriteShard",
        "db" : "admin"
    }
]
```

}

All ok. But I still get this error:

> not authorized on admin to execute command

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have permissions on the admin database to run the command. You will need to have privileges createUser and grantRole on the admin database.